# VSTS: Publish build artifacts to Azure File Storage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-storage-files

Is it possible to publish the output from a build on Visual Studio Team Services to Azure File Storage? I have looked at the **Azure File Copy** task but can see no way to copy to to anything but Azure Blob Storage or VMs with this. I was thinking I could possibly use AzCopy to achieve this but it seems like this should be supported out of the box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/it-it/docs/build/steps/deploy/azure-file-copy), We know that it only support copy files to Azure Blob Storage and VMs at currently. I think it does not support Azure File Storage currently. As a workaround, please use a custom script to copy files to Azure File Storage. Please also submit this request at [Visual Studio Team Services feature request forum](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as such and have submitted a [feature request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16540528-support-azure-file-storage-in-azure-file-copy-bu). Please vote it up! In the meantime I'll pursue the custom script to achieve this using AzCopy.